# What are scoreboards on Diep.io?

Tags: diep.io

What is the scoreboard on Diep.io?

I am specifically talking about the thing in the top-right corner, that has the text Scoreboard and has 10 things below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are scoreboards:

[image: scoreboard example]

### FFA and Sandbox

There are many parts to a scoreboard. The below is a scoreboard from a typical FFA game, but all of these rules apply to Sandbox mode as well.

[image: Typical FFA scoreboard]

There are far more than 10 players playing on that FFA server, but the scoreboard only displays the top 10 people. At the top would be the player `a savage.` with 195.6 thousand points, shown next to their name. They are playing as a Spike, which can be seen at the end of their progress bar.

The progress bar compares the other people on the leaderboard to the top person. `{❂} haykam`, having 7.5k score, has an about 3.83% filled progress bar. Ninja with 136.2k score has a progress bar filled to about 69.6%.

### 2 Teams and 4 Teams

In Team Deathmatch of both 2 Teams and 4 Teams variants, the background color is not a mint green. Instead, it is the same color as the team the player is on. Otherwise, the rules are the same as FFA/Sandbox.

[image: Team gamemode leaderboards]

`[MG]SNIPEpro` (a Necromancer) is on team red, while `necromancer` (a Necromancer) and `:0` (a Battleship) are on team blue.

[image: The two blues from before]

### Tag

In Tag, the scoreboard counts the number of players in each of the 4 teams (on mobile diep.io, there are only 2 teams) with their colors as the background.

[image: Tag leaderboard]

In this Tag example, there are 2 players on blue, 1 on purple, 1 on green, and 0 on red.

### Domination

On Domination, there is no leaderboard.

[image: Proof that there is no leaderboard on Domination]